# This line of code is supposed to draw a graph. But it is not plotting anything. It is just showing the axes

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I'm using jjoe64 graphview library
//Draws Graph

```
GraphView graph = findViewById(R.id.plot);
graph.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
DataPoint[] data = new DataPoint[term];
for (int i=0;i<term;i++){
   data[i] = new DataPoint(i+1,P * java.lang.Math.pow(1 + (r) / 100, i));
}
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(data);
graph.addSeries(series);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixed it:

```
graph.removeAllSeries();
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>();

    for (int i=1;i<=term;i++){
        int x=i;
        long y=Math.round(P * java.lang.Math.pow(1 + (r) / 100, i));
        series.appendData(new DataPoint(x,y),true,term);
    }

    graph.addSeries(series);
```